# World of Warcraft: Classic and quest difficulty

Tags: world-of-warcraft-classic

I'm playing World of Warcraft: Classic, as a hunter and I'm completely new to this game. I'm trying to solo the entire game and I've read that it is possible as a hunter with the pet as the tank.

But now I'm having problems with a quest called the Relics of Awakening, I tried completing the quest at level 8 but I was unable to handle 2-3 guys attacking me at the same time.

So I played again after getting a saber as a pet, but still, the quest is hard, coz my pet is getting wrecked as 4-5 of these guys are swarming around her, and then crushes me afterwards.

I'd like some pointers on how to beat this quest solo.

Comment: You're going to have an issue tanking at a low level, being level 8 isn't going to help you - if you wanna tank those you should aim to be level 10-11 with the pet - pet tanking is viable, however, the higher you are the more realistic you need to be.

Comment: There are various tricks to take advantage, some you will learn yourself, but it would be faster to find some good guide about your class, with description of each and every skill, talent, item and other useful information. Some quests are harder, do those later, you will be stronger by level or gear. You mention you have problem with running away mob - learn your CC (crowd control) skills and buffs to disable and quickly finish him. Pull next mob when skills are not on cooldown.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is run away when a group is attacking you, and hit just one of them (for example with arcane shot). The rest of the group will give up, and you can kill the single one. Rinse and repeat until the group is small enough to take on.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that but the one I'm attacking usually runs away in fear near death and it alerts the rest:(

Answer (score 1):

Try to kill 1 mob as fast as you can. Use you all abilities. Use your heal ability, to heal your pet. Or find someone who need this quest too.
If you have slowing spells, use them to slow mobs, and then run back and shoot them.